# Decoding Firebase Realtime Database Snapshot Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database for my project, and when i read information from the database, I get an Object as an output.

```
final databaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
final posts = await databaseInstance.ref("Posts").once();
print(posts.snapshot.value);
```

The result I get is `{Test Post: {Description: testing 123123, Date: 19 Dec}}`. However, I do not want it in this form. How should I read it such that i can read the data such that when I want the date I only get 19 Dec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops I actually found an answer to my problem. The problem with it was that when firebase realtime database was returning the result to me, it was not really is json.
So I has to convert it to json by myself using the function `jsonEncode(data)`.
When code was run, `{Test Post: {Description: testing 123123, Date: 19 Dec}}` to `{"Test Post":{"Description":"testing 123123","Date":"19 Dec"}}`, which solves my problem as I could just take have `['Test Post']` behind the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class called post that has Description and date variables like so:

```
   class Post{
    final String description, date;
    
    Post({
    required this.description,
    required this.date,
    });
    
    factory Post.fromJson(json){
    return Post(
    description: json['description'],
    date: json['date'],
    );
}
}
```

now when you get the snapshot simply use it like this:

```
var result = posts.snapshot.value;

final post = Post.fromJson(result['Test Post']);
```

and you can use `post.date` to get your date

Comment: Apologies, but I get this error when I use your code: `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.`

Comment: ok try this var result = posts.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>;

Comment: It does not pose an error, but it posed an exception when running: `_CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)`